# Mini freewheel / overrunning clutch for stepper motor

Tags: gears, stepper-motor

I am looking for a mini freewheel, one that I could mount on a standard NEMA 17 stepper motor (or similar stepper). I want to use it with a pulley, such that it starts the motion of a wheel, which can then continue to rotate on its own. 
Does anybody have an idea where I could get such a freewheel? Most of what I have seen is either for bikes or cars - I just need a very small version.
Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to locate the desired component if you search for "one way bearing for rc helicopter." I also used the term "sprag clutch" but came back with industrial grade, industrial sized items, along with the poorly spelled "sprague" clutch bearing.

One such return shows an 8 mm inside diameter with a 22 mm outside diameter over a 9 mm depth for the bearing. A bit more than US$12.00 found on [vxb.com web site.](https://www.vxb.com/CSK8-One-way-Sprag-Freewheel-Backstop-Clutch-p/Kit8176.htm?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1IfO9r_Z3QIVh4zICh0X3gpQEAQYAiABEgJBovD_BwE)

[image: sprag bearing]

Comment: "Sprag Bearing" or "One Way Bearing" is what I'd search